# Create group in Manage metadata service application using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server, managed-metadata, taxonomy, global-navigation

I want to add group in Manage metadata service application using power shell.

I have try to find some options in web but they are for sites not for service application.

Any help will be appreciated!!